# What do you call something that happens on a cyclical basis?

Tags: word-request

What do you call something that happens on a cyclical basis or something that keeps on repeating? For example, wars keeps on happening. What do you call such things that keeps on happening? I thought of the adjective cyclical, but it's an adjective and not a noun, and I thought about cycle, but cycle is not an event, but a period of time that's longer than an event that keeps on happening, so it's not quite the word I am looking for.

Comment: what about "recurrence"?

Comment: A recurring event.

Comment: Can you make an example of a sentence or some specific context in which you intend to use the word? Does it need to be a noun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of something within a repetitive cycle is an [**iteration**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration):

> **1** : the action or a process of iterating or repeating: such as
>   **a** : a procedure in which repetition of a sequence of operations yields results successively closer to a desired result
>   **b** : the repetition of a sequence of computer instructions a specified number of times or until a condition is met
>   **2** : one execution of a sequence of operations or instructions in an iteration
>   **3** : VERSION, INCARNATION
>   // the latest *iteration* of the operating system

To use an example, the [Matrix Wiki](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_One) says this about Neo, the protagonist of the trilogy of *Matrix* movies (emphasis mine):

> During his meeting with the Architect, Neo learns a surprising truth about the Matrix. The Matrix is much older than Morpheus and the humans of Zion realize. The Architect explains that, in addition to two unstable versions of the Matrix, there have been five *iterations*, or cycles, of the Matrix. In each stable *iteration*, an incarnation of The One has appeared. Neo is the sixth One to appear in this sixth Matrix *iteration*.